# LNK2005 & LNK1169 error when use QMap between 2 dlls

Tags: c++, qt

I have an issue since 2days about an LNK2005 & LNK1169 error on MSVC 2015 (Qt 5.12.6)

My error is:

```
Core.lib(Core.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl QMap<int,double>::~QMap<int,double>(void)" (??1?$QMap@HN@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in xxx.obj
```

I have the error when i'm trying to compile a library (named AAA)
The library AAA use Core.dll and both use a 2nd lib named Common.dll. The type QMap<int,double> is used in each libraries.

When i'm looking xxx.obj (located in AAA), the only one usage i have of QMap<int,double>, is when i'm use a function that return a QMap and located in Core.dll

I have lot of function defined in Core and used in AAA but i never seen this error before.

I have check multiple things: trying to change the QMap with QVector, same type of error.
I don't have any "include cpp file"
I don't have the error when i'm using Clang or GCC to compile the project.
I don't have the error if i'm using a QMap<int,double>*, but i don't want to

I think it's an error related to the qmap template but i'm not sure

Do you have an idea? Thanks

Ps: i'v change the name of third lib (AAA) cause this is a code i use for my work and cannot share lot of things about it

Comment: Recommendation: Construct a [mre] (MRE) rather than trying to explain the code. Not only does the often lead you to the solution (because the MRE link describes a powerful divide and conquer-based debugging technique), done right, the MRE will look almost nothing like the code you need to keep private.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you statically linking to Qt? Do your dlls export the QMap symbols?

Comment: I'm working on a MRE and i'will edit my post if i can reproduce it easily
It's a bit difficult to create that cause i'm working on a projet with hundreds of files

Comment: Qt is not used statically. I don't have any dllexport about QMap, only on each class i use in the projet

Answer (score 0):

So, i have fix my pb by replacing each usage of QMap<int, double> by another object located in a third library.
I have seen multiple definition of QMap<int, double> in the dlls by using Dependency Walker and that why the code counln't compile.

But I don't know if is a problem with the compiler (MSVC2015) or with my code.

I have used these website to help me:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/43408/error-lnk2005-when-deriving-from-qvariantmap
- http://web.archive.org/web/20090323151858/https://mareq.com/2008/10/exporting-non-template-class-inherited.html